# Calculator in Java, function to show error. Netbeans

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, calculator

I have the code below
Java on NetBeans

```
package calc;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int n1;
    int n2;
    
    String  operacao = "";
    int control=0;
    
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Digite a operação desejada (+, -, *, /): ");
    operacao = entrada.nextLine();          

        
        System.out.println("Digite um valor: ");
    n1 = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("Digite um valor: ");
    n2 = Integer.parseInt(entrada.next());
    
    if(operacao.equals("+")) {
        System.out.println("O resultado da subtração é: " +(n1 + n2));
        control++;          
    }
    
    if(operacao.equals("-")) {
        System.out.println("O resultado da subtração é: " +(n1 - n2));
        control++;      
    }
    
    if(operacao.equals("*")) {
        System.out.println("O resultado da multiplicação é: " +(n1 * n2));
        control++;          
    }
    
    if(operacao.equals("/")) {
        System.out.println("O resultado da divisão é: " +(n1 / n2));
        control++;          
    }   
    }  
    }
}
```

The code is working normally, but I would like to add a function that when the person types something other than this + - * / it would show an error message. Something like: "wrong function" and the program ended there.
Can anyone help.
Thank you.

Comment: If you convert your chain of `if` stmts into `if-else`, or a `switch`, you can add an `else` if `operacao` doesn't hold a valid operator, or a `default` switch case.

Comment: Cool, but i don't know how to implement with if-else, how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something as simple as this,

```
String operators = "+-/*";
System.out.print("Digite a operação desejada (+, -, *, /): ");
operacao = entrada.nextLine();
if(!operators.contains(operacao))
{
 System.out.println("Wrong Function!");
 return;
}
```